# TFS SourcesDirectory is null/empty when used in Expression Editor

Tags: tfs, tfs-2012

I have a build definition which has **two** working folders specified. One of these has the following columns:

- Status: Active
- Source Control Folder: $/MyCompany/MyDivision/Solution2
- Build Agent Folder: $(SourceDir)\Solution2

I am trying to access this Build Agent Folder from within the Expression editor in TFS 2012?

I've tried SourcesDirectory but when it gets evaluated it is null/empty. Is there something specific I need to do to get SourcesDiretory to work in the expression editor? Or is there a better way to reference this specific build agent folder in it's entirety?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SourcesDirectory and indeed the BinariesDirectory are not set till later in the build. They are not immediately available at the start of the build.

Comment: any idea after which flow activity do these become available?